# How to force scons not to rebuild target

Tags: build, scons

I sometimes modify a source file, but I'm sure the corresponding target needs not being rebuilt (e.g. if I added only comments). How to tell scons to assume that this file did not change?
I want to do this only to reduce compilation time.

Another situation where avoiding a new build would be needed is for example when the build directory ("VariantDir") is being renamed, both in the SConstruct file and on the filesystem (then scons rebuilds everything, saying that there was no "previous build information").

Answer (score 0):

SCons is made to be "efficient" in that it won't allow you to build your program with out-dated files. Thus, it actually requires to preprocess the file to know if its content has actually changed and requires compilation. Unfortunately (or not), preprocessing is done in the same step as compiling (not the same step, but though the same command) so that compilation is done anyway.

Have you tried having a SConscript in the VariantDir as suggested [here](http://www.scons.org/wiki/VariantDir%28%29) as it could fix your renaming issue.